# Swift 3 how to encode struct & enum with NSCoding

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, nscoding

I have a animation class as following:

```
enum AnimationState: String {
    case idle = "idle"
    case walk = "walk"
}

struct Animation {
    let animationState: AnimationState
    //let facingDireaction: FacingDirection
    let speed: TimeInterval
    let textures: [SKTexture]
    let repeatForever: Bool
}

class AnimationComponent: GKComponent {
    var animations: [AnimationState: Animation]

   //Other codes.....
}
```

I'm trying to encode animations as following:

```
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.animations, forKey: "AnimationComponent.animations") 
    }
```

and I get following errors when trying to encode animations variable:
_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000075540

My understanding is that I have to do some extra work to encode struct & enum, but how?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `NSCoding` supports only classes.

Comment: @vadian does that mean structs and enums could be declared as properties of a class, then the class made NSCoding compliant?

Comment: No, any **object** which is not property list compliant must be encoded. The Swift native structs `String`, `Int`, `Double`, `Bool`, `Data` and `Date` are bridged to the corresponding Foundation *classes*.

Comment: Any solutions to my problem? Does it mean I can't save the game by using NSCoding?

Comment: you can use NSCoding to encode the instances of your enums / structs via methods / inlining. To do so you first have to convert them to something NSCoding can understand... that is, a compliant key... the method would then parse that key and create the correct object. @Confused , Bob NSCoding is a big pain and you are better off using Plists / UserDefaults and dictionaries / arrays of strings for everything, then creating your own save / load functions as needed. Much less code.